# Yii2 and ActiveForm: add HTML code in radiolist text option

Tags: php, html, yii2, active-form

I need to show images instead of text in the radiolist options.

Now I have this:

`<?= $form->field($model, 'status')
     ->radioList([1 => '<i class=\'fa fa-play\'></i>', 0 => '<i class=\'fa fa-stop\'></i>'],['class' => 'statusRadio'])
     ->label('Status',['class'=>'labelStatus']) ?>`

but is not working, I'm seeing the html code and not the image. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the custom HTML as item in options

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'status')->radioList(
    [1 => "<i class='fa fa-play'></i>",0 => "<i class='fa fa-stop'></i>"],
    [
         'item' => function($index, $label, $name, $checked, $value){
               return $label." <input type='radio' name='".$name."' value='".$value."'> <br>";
         }
    ]
 )->label('Status',['class'=>'labelStatus']) ?>
```